# My attempt to KandR C ex1-21 entab needs assistance

Tags: c

Hi Gigantic C Newborn here

I am trying to solve the entab question in KandR C Programming and I have run into a rather silly problem.
In trying to solve it I am counting all the spaces when they get up to multiples of 8, and if they are, I have a loop that should step backward and remove the prior seven spaces, and then make the zeroth space a '#' to represent a tab. If the spaces dont count up to 8, the spaces should be represented by a '.' If the tab key is pressed, the user also gets a '#'.
My problem is when I count up to 8, the spaces do not get removed, and if I count up to 9, I get a '.#'.

Please can you show me what is wrong with my newbie code?

```
#define TAB 8
#define SPACE 1
#define MAXLINE 10000

int entab(char line[], int limit);

int main(void)
{
    char aline[MAXLINE];
    int lenline = 0;

    while((lenline = entab(aline, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        ;
    return 0;
}

int entab(char line[], int limit)
{
    int count = 0;
    int c, a;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && count < limit - 1)
    {
        switch(c){
            case ' ':
                if(count != 0 && (count % TAB == 0))
                {
                    a = count;
                    while(a > (count - TAB) -1)
                    {
                        line[a] = '\0';
                        --a;
                    }

                    line[count] = '#';
                    ++count;
                }
                else
                {
                    line[count] = '.';
                    ++count;
                }
                 break;
            case '\t':
                if (count < TAB)
                {
                    line[count] = '#';
                    ++count;

                }
                break;
            default:
                line[count] = c;
                ++count;
                break;
        }
    }

    line[count] = '\0';

    printf("\"");
    for(int each = 0; each < count; ++each)
        printf("%c", line[each]);
    printf("\"");
    printf("\n");
    return count;
}
```

My output is:
When typing 8 spaces:
    ./ex1-21

```
    "........"
```

When typing 9 spaces:
        "#"

Grateful for any pointers!

Comment: You're trying to get too much out of variable `count`.  It records the number of valid characters currently stored in the array, but its value contain *no* information about how many of the trailing characters are (or represent) spaces.  You need to keep a separate count of that, which you increment when you see a space and reset when you see anything else.

Comment: Thanks! I did something that worked, though its very ugly to see.

Comment: `            case ' ':
                line[count] = '.';
                ++count;
                ++a;
               if(a == TAB)
               {
                   line[count - a] = '#';
                   count = count - a + 1;
               }

                break;
`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to move count backwards near

```
                a = count;
                while(a > (count - TAB) -1)
                {
                    line[a] = '\0';
                    --a;
                }

                line[count] = '#';
                ++count;
```

Comment: Hi Joshua thanks I tried that before I posted but it didn't help.